# Plotting multiple graphs of variable number of points from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the form:

```
pid pred
1   0.5
1   0.6
1   0.8
2   0.2
2   0.6
3   0.6
3   0.6
3   0.8
3   0.7
...
```

Now, I want to, for each pid, plot a line graph between 0 and 1 (points regularly spaced) of the pred values onto the same canvas. Ordinarily, I would just convert this to an array and plot accordingly, but the problem here is that each pid does not necessarily have the same number of entries. For example, if there are two entries I would want the first point plotted at x=0, and the second at x=1. If there are three entries then the x coordinates for these should be x=0, x=0.5, x=1.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve looping over each pid individually and gradually adding to the plot?

As a supplementary query: If there were "dates" associated for each point, would there be a way to plot the points according to the relative time between them? E.g.: If the times are 0, 2, 10, then I would want the second point plotted at x=0.2 instead of x=0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `cumcount` and `size` to get the array of x-values within each `pid`. There are several ways to plot the lines, here I'll just loop over the groups.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df['x'] = df.groupby('pid').cumcount()/(df.groupby('pid')['pred'].transform('size')-1)
#   pid  pred         x
#0    1   0.5  0.000000
#1    1   0.6  0.500000
#2    1   0.8  1.000000
#3    2   0.2  0.000000
#4    2   0.6  1.000000
#5    3   0.6  0.000000
#6    3   0.6  0.333333
#7    3   0.8  0.666667
#8    3   0.7  1.000000

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
for pid, gp in df.groupby('pid'):
    gp.plot(x='x', y='pred', ax=ax, label=pid, marker='o')     
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

For your second question, if you have a `time` then we can normalize it between 0-1 by subtracting off the smallest value and dividing by the range within each `pid`. This works even for groups that don't begin the time at 0.

```
print(df)
pid pred time
1   0.5    0
1   0.6    2
1   0.8   10
2   0.2   -8
2   0.7   10
2   1.8   20
2   0.9   30

df['x'] = ((df['time']-df.groupby('pid')['time'].transform('min'))
              .div(df.groupby('pid')['time'].transform(np.ptp)))
#   pid  pred  time         x
#0    1   0.5     0  0.000000
#1    1   0.6     2  0.200000
#2    1   0.8    10  1.000000
#3    2   0.2    -8  0.000000
#4    2   0.7    10  0.473684
#5    2   1.8    20  0.736842
#6    2   0.9    30  1.000000
```